# Correct way to convert an improper list to a proper list in scheme?

Tags: scheme

Is there a built-in way to convert an improper list / pair / dotted pair to a proper list in scheme? I feel like there must be, I just can't find it. Instead I've been using the following.

```lisp
(define (make-proper improper-list)
  (if (proper-list? improper-list) improper-list
    (if (pair? improper-list)
      (cons (car improper-list) 
          (make-proper (cdr improper-list)))
      (cons improper-list '()))))

; (make-proper '(1 2 3 . 4))  ;=> (1 2 3 4)
; (make-proper (cons 1 2))    ;=> (1 2)
```

Is there a built-in way to do this? If not, is there a better solution than mine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`flatten`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._flatten%29%29). It's easy to [implement](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bscheme%5D+flatten+is%3Aquestion) in case that your interpreter doesn't include it already.

```
(flatten '(1 2 3 . 4))
=> (1 2 3 4)

(flatten (cons 1 2))
=> (1 2)
```

Comment: in Chicken scheme that just wraps a list around it: `(flatten '(1 2 3 . 4)) ;=> 
((1 2 3 . 4))`

Comment: thinking about it more, an improper list like `'(1 . 2)` shouldn't result in either `(1 2)` or `((1 . 2))` --  a) it doesn't contain any sublists so it shouldn't change, b) flatten shouldn't (conceptually) wrap things in lists.